# I couldn't read my page fileds value that are inside a uopdatepanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a problem with UpdatePanel.I have wrote this simple code:

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
                    </asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btn_AddPic" runat="server" OnClick="btn_AddPic_Click" Text="Button" />
                            </div>
                            <asp:Label ID="lbl_temp" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I change lbl_temp value by jquery but when I try to read it's value in server side,I show that it's empty.what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel is a container. You need to find control inside it:

```
Dim myValue = DirectCast(Me.UpdatePanel1.FindControl("lbl_temp"), Label).Text
```

Comment: Can you show the jquery code by which you are changing the lbl_temp value

Comment: jquey works and changes the lable value.my problem is why I dont see the changed value in code behind

Comment: Ow, I simply overlooked the fact that you are changing a _label_ with jQuery!! My bad. Sorry. @Adil saw it correctly, he is right. You need to either change the label thru code-behind, or copy it to a hidden input or any input with a display set to none.